# Trouble instaling ML.NET Model Builder package

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, ml.net, automl, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I´m trying to install ML.NET 1.0 package into Visual Studio 2017, so I can practice the ML.NET Model Builder,

[image: Preview]

Then I get the flollowing message:

[image: Error]

This is my Visual Studio installation

[image: This is my Visual Studio installation]

So I wolud like to know I someone have the same problem, and how to solve it.

Comment: I think you should open them a bug.

Comment: If it's ok, can you translate what the error is saying? Just the first sentence or so should be ok, but I can't tell what the issue is. Thanks!